# Maven fails on Jenkins (Target repository cannot be empty) but not local

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a simple maven project that successfully runs local but fails when running on Jenkins.

The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example.abc.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dev-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DEV-TEST</name>
    <modules>
        <module>dev-test-abc</module>
        <module>dev-test-assemblies</module>
    </modules>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactory.example.org</id>
            <name>artifactory.example.org-releases</name>
            <url>http://artifactory.example.org:8081/artifactory/project-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>artifactory.example.org</id>
            <name>artifactory.example.org-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://artifactory.example.org:8081/artifactory/project-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <name>Artifactory maven repository</name>
            <url>http://artifactory.example.org:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>plugin-artifactory</id>
            <name>Artifactory maven repository</name>
            <url>http://artifactory.example.org:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I run it local with `mvn clean install` on Jenkins it fails with the maven plugin.

On Jenkins I got following:

```
[INFO] DEV-TEST::ABC ......................... FAILURE [  2.928 s]
[INFO] DEV-TEST::ASSEMBLIES .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] DEV-TEST .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
... ... ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target repository cannot be empty -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target repository cannot be empty
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:129)
```

The pom of the failing module is here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example.abc.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>dev-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>dev-test-abc</artifactId>
    <name>DEV-TEST::ABC</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

As it is running local I guess that it is something with the maven settings that are in "C:/users/USER/.m2/settings.xml" is there something that could cause that error - that could be moved to the project pom to make it possible building on Jenkins with success?

As a note: Other Projects on the Jenkins building successful - so I guess it is something missing in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select target repository however looks is missing the publisher tag. You can use plugin called **maven artifactory** the link below there are examples and guide about it:

[artifactory-maven-plugin-example-and-guide](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/artifactory-maven-plugin-example)

Comment: As a note: Other Projects on the Jenkins building successful - so I guess it is something missing in the POM. But even with that information of you I'm not sure ... is there a way to get more information form maven about that? (I used -e -X)

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the Artifactory plugin.
See: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-241

Comment: As a note: Other Projects on the Jenkins building successful - so I guess it is something missing in the POM.